# Install "Android M2e" Plugin or basically "Android Configurator for M2E 0.4.2" in Eclipse Mobile Juno

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

Trying to install Android M2e plugin as given on http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/ with no luck. I am getting this exception for "Android Configurator for M2E 0.4.2"

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Configurator for M2E 0.4.2 (me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group 0.4.2)
  Missing requirement: Android Configurator for M2E 0.4.2 (me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group 0.4.2) requires 'org.eclipse.persistence.moxy 2.1.0' but it could not be found**

I am using Eclipse Juno for Mobile Developers. I tried with "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and it was giving me same error as well.

This is my eclipse info

> **Eclipse for Mobile Developers Version: Juno Release Build id: 20120614-1722**

I also went to the plugin website directly on github https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/blob/master/me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature/feature.xml and found that it requires following plugins

```
<requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="3.5.1" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.5.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.launching" version="3.5.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="1.2.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.console" version="3.4.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.persistence.moxy" version="2.1.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="javax.xml.bind"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <import feature="org.eclipse.m2e.feature" version="1.0.200.20111228-1245"/>
      <import feature="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" version="17.0.0.v201203161636-291853"/>
   </requires>
```

Do anyone know how to install **org.eclipse.persistence.moxy** plugin? I am suspecting that this must be bundled with some other plugin or so. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junorc3) 
This version of Eclipse has all the Required jars & Plugins.

Comment: Have you done all these? [Prerequisites](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted#Prerequisites) if you have done that here is the [Moxy.Jar file](http://rpm.scl.rs/eclipse/releases/juno/201202030900/aggregate/features/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.4.0.v20120126-r10746.jar) put it in Eclipse/plugins folder & restart, might work

Comment: @CharlesMunger I don't have any idea about that, plz let me know once you know the solution. :)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

When I checked "Available Software Sites" in Window > Preferences > Install/Update, all the Juno software sites had disappeared! I don't know why this has happened but this was the reason Eclipse could not resolve the missing dependencies.

The easiest solution is to add back Juno repo in the "Available Software Sites":

- Name: Eclipse Juno repository
- Location: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: Many thanks. I installed eclipse as a different user and when I accessed it from another one found it didn't have any software sites thanks to this tip. By the upvote count I'd say it looks like the wrong answer got accepted...

Comment: Just had a similar issue with 4.3 Kepler RC1 for Java developers, where the new repositories don't seem to be yet available. Adding the Juno repository fixed it for me, thanks.